# Excel like Data Grid Control in PHP

Tags: php

I need an excel-like data grid control to use in PHP. The most important feature I am looking for is the capability to 'add a comment' to each cell, like it happens in excel.

Any ideas, please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS can help you: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/

Answer (score 0):

[view-components/grids](https://github.com/view-components/grids) can help you.
There is no out of box 'add comment' functionality, but it cab be easily implemented.

- [Demo](http://vc-grids.herokuapp.com/index.php/demo11_1) ([sources](https://github.com/view-components/grids/blob/master/tests/webapp/Controller.php))
- [Ask questions here](https://github.com/view-components/grids/issues)